# FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY-OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

Hi we are using OBIEE 11g. We have a prompt which is taking data from a table which has 100k records, some records were not showing up. When I checked the backend query that was generated, I was able to see something like this

```
SELECT "Customer"."Customer Name" saw_0 FROM "Sales" 
WHERE UPPER("Customer"."Customer Name") LIKE UPPER('Rite%') ORDER BY saw_0
FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY
```

The last part is actually limiting the number of rows fetched. I googled it and found few posts asking to change this value in EM->coreapplication->capacity Management->Performace and set "**Max no of rows processed when rendering a table view**" to a higher value than 6500.But this value is already set to 500k.

How do I get rid of this last limiting part of the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a limitation in the version we are using(11.1.1.6.7).

Raised an SR with Oracle and confirmed the same.

"**Your SR indicates you're running version 11.1.1.6.7. Unfortunately, with this version, there is no way to increase the number of rows returned to your prompt. This was changed in all versions more recent than the one you're running. Please see:
OBIEE 11g: Values Missing in a Column Filter Search Results List of Values when there are more than 65000 Rows Returned [( Doc ID 1554797.1 )](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1554797.1)**"

Answer (score 0):

There is an Oracle Knowledge article for this, [Doc ID 884712.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=884712.1)

That states that you need to edit the instanceconfig.xml and add the following within the `<ServerInstance>` tags. Obviously setting it to the value you want.

```
<Prompts><MaxDropDownValues>XXXX</MaxDropDownValues></Prompts>
```

6,500 values is already a lot for a select-based prompt though.

Comment: It is already set to 100k. I searched instance config for 6500 and 6501, no results. And the prompt we have is customer names, the agents will search the name and not select from the drop down.

Comment: 6,500 is the default value, and those properties are not in the instanceconfig.xml file until you add them.

If you've already added the property to the instance config (and restarted everything) and it's not working then I think you should raise a SR with Oracle.